Getting libarchive not found error while trying to publish to shinyapp
I have an rmd file with plots and I am trying to publish the .rmd file into my dedicated server. The process starts but then fails all of a sudden. I tried to google a solution but I cant seem to understand whats happening exactly.
this is the final error message I get
--------------------------- [ANTICONF] --------------------------------
Configuration failed because libarchive was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libarchive-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libarchive-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libarchive_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: libarchive (Mac OSX)
If libarchive is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libarchive.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
* installing to library ‘/usr/lib/R’
* installing *source* package ‘archive’ ...
** package ‘archive’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: archive.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘archive’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/archive’## End Task Log ################################################################
Error: Unhandled Exception: child_task=1406817497 child_task_status=failed: Error building image: Error building archive (1.1.7). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted

I am not very good with cmd and interpreting the outputs so if anyone can suggest some steps I can take to resolve this would be much appreciated.

What operating system are you using? The message in the ANTICONF section tells you what command you need to install depending on your operating system. For ubuntu, it would be something like apt install libarchive-dev

I am using a windows pc

Shiny server runs on another operating system called Linux. In R, the command version$platform can show which operating system R is running on.

The error message indicates that the archive package, which is required for building the archive (presumably your R Markdown document), cannot be found. This is because a dependency, libarchive, is missing from your systemm
Here's how to resolve this issue:

Install libarchive:

Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt install libarchive-dev
Fedora/CentOS/RHEL: sudo yum install libarchive-devel
Solaris: csw install libarchive_dev
macOS (Homebrew): brew install libarchive


After installation, retry building your R Markdown document.
If libarchive is already installed, you might need to adjust your environment variables to ensure pkg-config finds the libarchive.pc file. Refer to the full error message for moore details on how to set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually.

